# Instances for nested, parameterized types

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Given that I have the data types

```
data A a = A a
data B b = B b
```

and the type class

```
class C c where
    f :: c a -> a
```

Now the class C expects a type of kind `* -> *`, so I can do

```
instance C A where
    f (A a) = a

instance C B where
    f (B b) = b
```

Now given a function such as:

```
ab :: b -> A (B b)
ab = A . B
```

How would I declare an instance of `C` for the result type?

I first through I might be able to use a type synonym with `TypeSynonymInstances`, like this:

```
type AB b = A (B b)
class C AB where
    f (A (B b)) = b
```

Especially since ghci reports the correct kind:

```
*Main> :k AB
AB :: * -> *
```

However, you can't seem to use partially applied type synonyms in instance declarations (or anywhere, for that matter).

Is there some way I can compose the types `A` and `B` like I can compose the constructors, or some other syntax for declaring an instance for such a nested type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest is probably to define

```
newtype AB a = AB { unAB :: A (B a) }
```

GHC should be able to derive a C instance for this.

You could also use [TypeCompose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose) to accomplish this,

```
type AB = A :. B

instance C AB where
  f = f . f . unO
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to declare such an instance.  In fact, allowing arbitrary type functions such as `AB` in instance declarations makes instance resolution undecidable.

Usually, the solution is to declare a newtype.  Of course, you will have to explicitly convert to and from the newtype when you want to use the class.

```
newtype AB a = AB (A (B a))
instance C AB where f (AB (A (B a)) = a
```

If your usage of the class is simple enough, you may want to just pass the overloaded method as a parameter of functions that use it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `newtype`. A type synonym must always be applied completely, as it is only a synonym, not a lambda. A `newtype` has no runtime penalty; it will be removed when compiling.